# Template disambiguator accepted for non-template function

Tags: c++, templates

This code

```
template <typename U>
struct Bar{
    void setNumber(int) {}
};

template <int N>
struct Asd : public Bar<Asd<N>>{
    void doSomething();
};

template<int N>
inline void Asd<N>::doSomething() {
    this->template setNumber(N);
}

int main() {
    Asd<42> obj;
    obj.doSomething();
}
```

is accepted by GCC (even 13.1 and trunk) but rejected by clang (https://godbolt.org/z/xbs8GqG7h).
Accepting it seems wrong (`setNumber` is not a template function) so I believe this is a bug in GCC. Can somebody quote chapter and verse that makes this explicit?

I tried searching the GCC bugzilla for "disambiguator", but got only unrelated bugs.

Answer (score 5):

[[temp.names]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.names#6.sentence-1):

> A name prefixed by the keyword `template` shall be followed by a template argument list or refer to a class template or an alias template.

Here the name `setNumber`

- is not followed by a template argument list;
- does not refer to a class template;
- does not refer to an alias template.

So it's wrong to accept this syntax.

Comment: Thanks, I've created https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=110300